# How is Information Gain Biased?

Tags: cart, information-theory

Why is the following statement true: Information gain is biased towards variables with more outcomes?

I've seen the following statement and close variants quite frequently: "information gain shows unfair favoritism towards attributes with many outcomes."

I'm having a very hard time conceptualizing this in regards to a classification decision tree. I've seen the claim multiple times, but I haven't found an example with data yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it more precisely, the information gain (mutual information) is always biased upward. It is severely biased when two conditions meet: you have small sample, and you have many variable levels. This stems from the fact that in general practice one calculates **naive** information gain, or in other words, a sample estimate (point estimate). This estimate will almost surely be affected by deviations of observed probability estimates from theoretical. More variable levels multiplied by lower number of observations will exaggerate the observed probability deviations. It is called the limited sampling bias.

There are robust estimations of information metrics which can somehow decrease the bias. One read that goes into detail: http://people.sissa.it/~ale/Pan+96a.pdf (Analytical estimates of limited sampling biases in different information measures, by Stefano Panzeri et al.)